# pythonic way to flatten or expand a dict to list of dicts in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose values are list-objects.

```py
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

I want to **expand** (for lack of a right word) the dict into the following:

```py
 [{'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6}]
```

I have a solution that looks a little non-Pythonic, ugly and hackish to me.

```py
def flatten_dict(d: dict) -> list[dict]:
    """
    get [{'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5}] from {'a': [1, 2], 'b': [4, 5]}

    :param d: dict object
    :return: list of dicts
    """
    values = list(d.values())
    val_zip = list(zip(*values))

    keys = [list(d.keys())] * len(values[0])

    bonded_vals = list(zip(keys, val_zip))
    return list(map(lambda p: dict(zip(p[0], p[1])), bonded_vals))
```

Please help/direct me to a suitable Python feature that does something similar and improves the code readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```py
dct = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6]}

out = [dict(zip(dct, t)) for t in zip(*dct.values())]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[{'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think resigning from `lambda` and `map` improves readability on its own by a ton. This is matter of opinion though.

```py
def flatten_dict(d: dict[str, list[int]]) -> list[dict[str, int]]:
    longest = max(len(v) for v in d.values())
    results = [dict() for _ in range(longest)]

    for name, values in d.items():
        for idx, number in enumerate(values):
            results[idx][name] = number

    return results
```

For input (I added a 3rd key-value pair with different number of elements):

`x = {"a": [1, 2, 3], "b": [4, 5, 6], "c": [11, 22, 33, 44]}`

produces output:

`[{'a': 1, 'b': 4, 'c': 11}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5, 'c': 22}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6, 'c': 33}, {'c': 44}]`